# Python - Regex to avoid matching duplicates

Tags: python, regex

My string looks like this:

```
bo_1
bo_1
bo_2
bo_2
bo_3
bo_3
bo_4
bo_4
bo_5
bo_5
bo_6
bo_6
bo_7
bo_7
bo_8
bo_8
bo_9
bo_9
bo_10
bo_10
```

I want to match the first instance of each digit and ignore the next duplicate line. My regex is as follows:

```
(bo_\d)(?![\s\S]*\1)
```

which returns the following:

```
'bo_2'
'bo_3'
'bo_4'
'bo_5'
'bo_6'
'bo_7'
'bo_8'
'bo_9'
'bo_1'
```

How would I modify the regex to return a result like this instead (to include 'bo_1' at the start and 'bo_10' at the end):

```
'bo_1'
'bo_2'
'bo_3'
'bo_4'
'bo_5'
'bo_6'
'bo_7'
'bo_8'
'bo_9'
'bo_10'
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't need regex for that (you can use `set()` for instance):

```
>>> # Assume your string is in the variable called "text"
>>> result = set(text.split('\n'))
>>> result
{'bo_7', 'bo_3', 'bo_1', 'bo_6', 'bo_5', 'bo_8', 'bo_9', 'bo_2', 'bo_4', 'bo_10'}
```

Anyway, the issue with your regex is that `bo_1` is also matching `bo_10`, so it will be seen as a duplicate by the regex. You can solve it using word boundaries to ensure that the full 'word' is tested for a match:

```
\b(bo_\d+)\b(?![\s\S]*\b\1\b)
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/IvuT8T/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(bo_\d+$)(?![\s\S]*^\1$)
```

Since you want to include `bo_10`, you should use `\d+` and not just `\d` in the initial group. Then, in your negative lookahead, put the backrefrence *between* start-of-line and end-of-line anchors, so that, for example, `bo_1` does not get excluded because it's followed by a `bo_10`.

https://regex101.com/r/8khbcc/1

Comment: If the regex isn't important, you can add them all into a set and it will remove duplicates by nature.  I typically wouldn't rely on regex to do your duplication prevention when there are a lot of other tools at your disposal, but that'd be outside the scope of the question.